# Using Named Pipes in C#

Tags: c#, named-pipes, win32exception

i've been trying to use Named Pipes in C# for a while but can't get it to work.
I'm working with the following code:

```
internal class SplitManager
{
    public static void initialize()
    {
        Debug.Log("Initializing LiveSplit pipe");
        SplitManager.pipeClientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream("//.//pipe//LiveSplit");
        Debug.Log("Successfully initialized LiveSplit pipe");
    }

    public static void startRun()
    {
        Debug.Log("[PIPE]: start");
        SplitManager.WriteString("start");
    }

    public static void performSplit()
    {
        Debug.Log("[PIPE]: split");
        SplitManager.WriteString("split");
    }

    private static void WriteString(string str)
    {
        SplitManager.pipeClientStream.Connect();
        new StreamString(SplitManager.pipeClientStream).WriteString(str);
        SplitManager.pipeClientStream.Close();
    }

    private static NamedPipeClientStream pipeClientStream;
}

public class StreamString
{
    public StreamString(Stream ioStream)
    {
        this.ioStream = ioStream;
        this.streamEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
    }

    public string ReadString()
    {
        int num = this.ioStream.ReadByte() * 256;
        num += this.ioStream.ReadByte();
        byte[] array = new byte[num];
        this.ioStream.Read(array, 0, num);
        return this.streamEncoding.GetString(array);
    }

    public int WriteString(string outString)
    {
        byte[] bytes = this.streamEncoding.GetBytes(outString);
        int num = bytes.Length;
        if (num > 65535)
        {
            num = 65535;
        }
        this.ioStream.WriteByte((byte)(num / 256));
        this.ioStream.WriteByte((byte)(num & 255));
        this.ioStream.Write(bytes, 0, num);
        this.ioStream.Flush();
        return bytes.Length + 2;
    }

    private Stream ioStream;

    private UnicodeEncoding streamEncoding;
}
```

When i run this code i get `Win32Exception` with an error message that it cannot find the specified file. I'm 100% sure the path is fine, since i checked it with powershell command `[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\\pipe\\")`. Any ideas why does this error happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that C# actually provides the "//.//pipe//" prefix to the string, so simply replacing `SplitManager.pipeClientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream("//.//pipe//LiveSplit");` to `SplitManager.pipeClientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream("LiveSplit");` worked!